# Approving edits

Tags: discussion, edits, suggested-edits

I've recently starting getting notifications about edits to my posts, asking me to review them. But when I go to the post, it shows that the edits were already approved by someone else. Can someone explain to me why someone other than me is allowed to approve edits to my post (assuming we're not talking about obscenity or anything like that)?

If the ability to review changes exists, why am I not offered the opportunity to deny the changes? In this case, someone edited my original code because he assumed I had a typo in it. I didn't - the code I had posted was exactly what was generated by the system I'm working with. Now I have to go back and change my original post again, and possibly have someone else change it back without my approval.

Comment: I note with some irony that Giles has edited this post for you already :)

Comment: You mean [this suggestion](http://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/283552) by any chance? What's so wrong about it that you want to roll it back?

Comment: @ShaDowWizArd - if I'm not allowed to ask why people downvoted a post or comment, it doesn't seem fair that I should have to justify why I want to roll back an edit that I didn't approve. But as it happens, the css code that was modified was correct as it was - the hyphen that the editor removed IS actually there and generated by the view that I was given to work with.

Comment: You don't have to, just wondering what's wrong to learn from this case myself. After you roll back you can also notify the one who suggested the edit of his mistake (using `@name`) - so that he can learn from his mistake. Cheers and happy programming! :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All your posts on any Stack Exchange site can be edited by anybody, even anonymous users. However, edits by people with less than 2000 rep on the site have to be approved by one, or on Stack Overflow two, user(s) with edit privileges, as a measure to prevent spam and bad edits. (That isn't working perfectly, of course, mistakes happen.)

When as edit to one of your posts is suggested by a `< 2000` rep user, you get a notification about that (maybe you even get a notification if a user with edit privileges edits one of your posts), and you may vote to approve or reject that edit. However, if the edit has been approved (or rejected) by sufficiently many reviewers (one or two, depending on the site), the decision about that edit is made.

However, if the edit was bad, you can easily roll back to the previous version (the edit will appear in the revision history, if that is a *serious problem*, the deletion of the bad revision can be requested, but usually, it's no cause for worry).

All in all, the system does more good than bad, since it allows many people to fix your (not yours personally, the generic you) typos and other errors. The relatively small number of bad edits that pass the review process can be rolled back with relatively little effort.

Comment: OK, that makes sense. Where can I find the revision history that would allow me to roll it back? I don't see anything in the review page.

Comment: On the question there's an "edited X time ago by Y" box to the left of the user's signature, click the time link and it'll show you the revision history. You can roll back the revision if you don't agree with how it changed your post, or make your own edits to the new verison.

Comment: In this case, I think you'd want to scroll to revision 3 and click the `rollback` link, @EmmyS.

Comment: Thanks, @Shadow. The typo was entirely unintentional, in case anybody wonders.

Comment: @Daniel lol I know but it glared it me, I glared back and couldn't resist!

Comment: Why should you, @ShaDowWizArd, it was an error. I just wish I had been devious enough to do it on purpose.

Comment: Usually I don't do such minor edits, prefer to leave comment and let the OP do it - full scale edit just seem too "heavy" to fix one letter. But yeah, can see your point - this is perfect example why edits improve the contents. :)

Comment: Yes, true. One-character-edits should be the exception. But what needs to be done, needs to be done ;)

Answer (score 3):

This site is a wiki, a collaborative project.  Everyone is able to edit anything; well, except that users who are relatively new to the site (as measured by reputation) can only suggest edits that a person relatively well known on the site must choose to approve.

You can also review the edit history of your post, showing who, why did what to your post.  If a disservice happened, it may be a consolation to go and suggest edits to the offender's other posts as well.  And your edit seems good enough to a reviewer - your edits may get approved without the offender's knowledge and you will have your revenge!

No, just kidding.  Simply roll such changes to your own post back and maybe edit your post to make your intention harder to misunderstand the next time if possible.